# Drawing 4 balls from an urn without replacement and a bonus ball

Tags: probability

An urn contains 9 white, 9 red, 9 blue and 9 green balls.  4 balls are drawn randomly without replacement and a fifth bonus ball is drawn from the same urn.

a)  What is the probability of drawing 3 red balls and a non-red bonus ball?

b)   What is the probability of drawing 2 black balls and 1 black bonus ball?

I managed to use a general formula for drawing 5 balls but I cannot modify it for the required solution.  Please refer to the attached images for my progress.

[Drwing 5 Balls straight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58tjp.jpg)

[Drawing 4 + 1 balls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3vm8.jpg)

Comment: Hint: look at the balls drawn as a random permutation, and work on that

Comment: On a) apply: P(3 red and non-red bonus)=P(non-red bonus|3 red)P(3 red). Sortlike for b).